# Getting null bean value in java rest while passing JSON array through $http in angularJs

Tags: java, angularjs, json, rest

I want to send JSON array to my java rest metrthod which contains two same bean properties. Here's my Angular $http method

```js
                  //Some code here
                  
                  tempJsonData = JSON.stringify(result);
                 jsonData="{\"employees\":"+tempJsonData+"}";
                 console.log(jsonData);
                 
                //Get the first column first cell value
                
             };
             
             $http({
           url: "rest/admin/upload",
           method: "POST",
           data: jsonData,
           headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
          
          }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
              if (data) {
              
                  $scope.data = data;
                  //$("#popupmodal1").openModal();
                 
              }
          }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
              alert("error");
          })
```

And my Json (var jsonData in angular) Looks like:

```
{"employees":[{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"},{"key1":"value3","key2":"value4"}]}
```

Here's my bean class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class EmployeeList {

    private ArrayList<EmployeeBean> employees;

    public ArrayList<EmployeeBean> getEmployees() {
        return employees;
    }

    public void setEmployees(ArrayList<EmployeeBean> employees) {
        this.employees = employees;
    }

}
```

This has only one property which is list of EmployeeBean.
Here's my REST method:

```
@POST
@Path("/upload")
@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Produces({ "application/json" })
public String upload(EmployeeList employees) {

if(employees!=null){
    for(EmployeeBean e:employees.getEmployees())
        System.out.println(e.getSignum());
}
else
    System.out.println("No data passed");

    return "{}";
}
```

But EmployeeList is not being populated, EmployeeList employees is always Null.

P.S.:

1)I have tried not creating separate class for List and passed List as a parameter to the rest directly, but still not working.

2)I have modified my JSON data from `[{"key1":"value1"},{"key1":"value2"}]` to `{"employees":[{"key1":"value1"},{"key1":"value2"}]}` 
Both not working.

Comment: Add @RequestBody in front of EmployeeList in the method parameter.